# custom sql operations on column-level in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

In Hibernate it is possible to override SQL operations on entity-level. There are many [examples](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#example-custom-crdu-via-annotations) how to do this.

In the Hibernate [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch13.html#querysql-cud) you can also read that it is possible to override SQL statements on column-level. Beside of hibernate annotations it is also possible to write it in the Hibernate-API:

```java
org.hibernate.mapping.Column.customWrite(String)
org.hibernate.mapping.Column.customRead(String)
```

But I don't know how to get my annotation-mapped entity work with the hibernate Column-Class

Does anybody know how to write sql statements for columns? How is it possible to get this things work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used @ColumnTransformer(write="") and it works well.

It helps you cherry pick a write-expression for a column which is inserted into the final query everytime an insert or update query is executed by hibernate.

Reference link: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/mapping.html#mapping-column-read-and-write